# I'm cetting an error while creating a React app: "enoent request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed"

Tags: reactjs, node.js, create-react-app, npx, npm-start

Versions

- node v20.11.1
- npm 10.2.4

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react js> npx create-react-app firstweb

node+×

X

npm ERRI code ENOENT

npm ERRI syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERRI errno ENOENT

npm ERRI enoent request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENDENT registry.n pmjs.org

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERRI A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\logs\2024-03-20T11_50_32_0

84Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried to create npm folder in roaming, I have uninstalled and installed the node js, but also it's giving the same error.

Comment: Create your react app in other directory rather then in Desktop.

Comment: It looks like NPM/NPX does not have access to the internet.

Comment: So what to do? How I can fix this error.